# Proper way to extract rows from a dataframe based on list values

Tags: python, pandas

For a dataframe with label `group` of some integers, what is the best way to get the sub-dataframe based on a list of group labels?

```
map = [[9,13],[21,22]]

train

         group  feature1
id
0          24 -0.141691
1          22 -0.527684
2          13 -0.586026
3           9  0.233221
4          21 -0.545011
```

Currently I am using for loop which obviously is sub-optimal.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in map[0]:
  new_df = pd.concat([df,train[train.group==i]],axis=0)

new_df           

             group feature1
    id
    2          13 -0.586026
    3           9  0.233221
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `pd.Series.isin`?

```
df[df['group'].isin(np.concatenate(map))]

    group  feature1
id                 
1      22 -0.527684
2      13 -0.586026
3       9  0.233221
4      21 -0.545011
```

If you want *just* the records associated with `map[0]`:

```
df[df['group'].isin(map[0])]

    group  feature1
id                 
2      13 -0.586026
3       9  0.233221
```

Comment: Nice, do the job!